# Preventing service from force stop

Tags: android, android-service

My application has a service for checking and downloading data from server. I have exited the application after starting service. Now the application and service are in the memory. I have force stopped the application (not service) from memory. Then my service is also stopped. How can I prevent stopping my service. If application is stopped by the OS, my service will be there or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If service and UI are sharing same process then FC in either part will cause both to be killed. However, your first approach should be to avoid getting FC errors. Track down to the reasons for this issue and if possible encapsulate critical parts of your code with in `try/catch` blocks.

Moreover, you should return `Service.START_STICKY` in **onStartCommand** of your service to re-create it in case its killed.

Comment: if OS is stopping the application the service will also be stopped. Will that service be resatrted?

Comment: i have no idea about iOS, but in android, if service is not stopped by you, then it should be restarted itself (unless there is severely low memory)